# Why is a SOAP call working from CFM page but not from a CFC page?

Tags: soap, coldfusion, wsdl, cfc

I am working with a SOAP request in coldfusion. When the code I have is run from a .CFM file, it works. If it is run from a .CFC file, it doesn't work. The code is the same as far as possible (the .CFC needs the cfcomponent and cffunction tags for example).

Why would it work from one and not the other? When I call it from the CFC page I get the error

[image: Error message]

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? The SOAP request is identical on both pages. The call with the `CFHTTP` as well as all the `CFHTTPPARAM`s are the same as well.

Here is the code for the CFC file:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="updateAgParcel" returntype="string" returnformat="plain" access="remote">
        <cfargument name="ag_pres_nr" required="true" type="string">
        <cfargument name="emp_nr" required="true" type="string">
        <cfargument name="dt_rcvd" required="true" type="string">
        <cfset dt_rcvd = DateFormat(#dt_rcvd#,"MMDDYYYY")>
        <cfsavecontent variable="soapBody">
            <cfoutput>
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ass="http://XXXXXX">
                   <soapenv:Header/>
                   <soapenv:Body>
                      <ass:LogAgPreserveFiling>
                            <ass:AG.PRES.NR>#ag_pres_nr#</ass:AG.PRES.NR>
                            <ass:TC>04</ass:TC>
                            <ass:EMP.NR>#emp_nr#</ass:EMP.NR>
                            <ass:LCAQ.DT.RCVD>#dt_rcvd#</ass:LCAQ.DT.RCVD>
                            </ass:LogAgPreserveFiling>
                    </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfsavecontent>

        <cfhttp url="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" method="post" result="httpResponse">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="accept-encoding" value="no-compression" />
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="text/xml" />
            <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#trim( soapBody )#" />
        </cfhttp>

        <cfif find( "200", httpResponse.statusCode )>
            <cfset soapResponse = xmlParse( httpResponse.fileContent ) />
            <cfset responseNodes = xmlSearch(soapResponse, "//*[ local-name() = 'VCfaultdetails'] ") />
            <cfif arrayLen(responseNodes) NEQ 0>
                <cfset error = #responseNodes[ 1 ].message.xmlText#>
                <cfreturn error>
            <cfelse>
                <cfreturn "">
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Code for the CFM version:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="soapBody">
    <cfoutput>
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ass="http://XXXXX">
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <ass:LogAgPreserveFiling>
                   <ass:AG.PRES.NR>#ag_pres_nr#</ass:AG.PRES.NR>
                   <ass:TC>04</ass:TC>
                   <ass:EMP.NR>#emp_nr#</ass:EMP.NR>
                   <ass:LCAQ.DT.RCVD>#dt_rcvd#</ass:LCAQ.DT.RCVD>
              </ass:LogAgPreserveFiling>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfhttp url="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" method="post" result="httpResponse">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="text/xml">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="accept-encoding" value="no-compression" />
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#trim( soapBody )#" />
</cfhttp>


<cfif find( "200", httpResponse.statusCode )>
    <cfset soapResponse = xmlParse( httpResponse.fileContent ) />
    <cfset responseNodes = xmlSearch( soapResponse, "//*[ local-name() = 'VCfaultdetails'] " ) />
    <cfif arrayLen(responseNodes) NEQ 0>
    <cfoutput>
        Code: #responseNodes[ 1 ].errorcode#
        <br />
        Message: #responseNodes[ 1 ].message#
    </cfoutput>
    <cfelse>
        Success!!!!!!!!
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

I XXXXXX out some of the URL's and such for security. Also, sorry for the namespace the developers choose (ass:). It was the abbreviation for Assessor. Somebody was being funny...

Comment: Please share your code from each. Something is different. It should work fine from either.

Comment: How are you invoking the CFC? And how are you initialising the params when using the CFM? The SOAP body + cfhttp calls look like they should be equivalent from what you have shown us, which suggests that the difference is likely to be in something we cannot see here.

Comment: Are both of these requests coming from different ColdFusion servers or JVMs? The error that sticks out to me is `I/O Exception: Remote host terminated the handshake` and `Connection Failure`. You 'X' out the protocol on URL also. Is it https? Looks like this might be a certificate issue.

Comment: I was just loading up each page to test initially (typing the url & parameters into the browser). In production I use an ajax call in jQuery to call the CFC. I was using http for both. I just changed this to https and it didn't like that at all. Then I changed them back to http and now both are working fine. This doesn't make any sense to me so my guess is that the problem was on the server hosting the web service. I've put in code to account for that now. Thank you all for you help!

Comment: That particular error message makes sense if your `cfhttp` call is to an https endpoint which uses `SNI` and you have an old version of CF/Java which did not support `SNI`, or if the call is to an https endpoint which requires a later and greater version of `TLS` than your version of CF/Java supports.